# How do I fix terrible image scaling in Apache FOP?

Tags: image, xsl-fo, apache-fop

We're currently using apache fop to render a bunch of images in PDF format, but we've notice that the quality of just about any image is complete garbage and anything with text in it is incredibly unreadable.

I have looked through the documentation about source and target resolutions [here.](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/configuration.html)

And I thought that maybe I could force fit some good image quality in by assuming a default (source) resolution of 72 pixels per inch for all bitmaps/pngs/etc and desiring a target resolution of 300 pixels per inch. I figured this would theoretically cause FOP to cram way more image into a smaller space netting me an increase in quality with less of a need to smash my images into such a small space. Also I did the math and before where things were 72 72 it seemed like we were getting 5 * 72 = 375 pixel Nokia phone screen resolutions so I was like no wonder they are terrible quality.

Well, it seems like even with a target PPI of 300 instead of netting me a generous space of about 1500 pixels, I'm still getting the same crappy Nokia phone quality. I tried many combinations of source and target PPI 300/300 72/300 and 300/72 respectively, but nothing seems to cause any form or resampling or better image output. In the end I'm always left with this.

[image: terrible image quality.]

This is an actual screenshot of my PDF at almost full screen size. It may be worth noting that we *are* using the org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 encoder to take images from memory and turn them into strings to embed into PDF. I don't know what kind of compression if any is being done through this encoder, but I hope to dump a string to the filesystem soon to take a look and make sure that isn't the issue.

In the meantime, does anyone know what PPI settings I might have messed up or what better options I may have to render clear cleaner images out to PDF with FOP?

Comment: What image format are you using?  According to the documentation, source resolution applies only to formats that don't have an intrinsic resolution.

Comment: The images we've tested are in PNG format. I haven't tested other formats, but I'll look at it shortly.

Comment: A PNG knows its own resolution, so the source resolution setting will not apply. Consider changing the resolution of the PNG to 300dpi and then doing a 'pixel resize' to the largest size at 300dpi that won't cause FOP to scale it down to fit the available space.